# Split string by "\" Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, split

Hy everyone, I'm having some issues with split a string because when I log her value seems ok but in the final result appears "\" like,

```
"map":"{\"isRoot\": true, \"visible\": true}" instead of have "map":"{"isRoot": true, "visible": true}"
```

So I have this code

```
if(mapData!=undefined){
    var map = mapData.map;
    console.log("sendDeviceInfo getServicesMapInfoById map  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ", map);
    sendData.map=map;
    createLog('debug', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), device.id, 'sendDeviceInfo','sendData.map 1', sendData.map);
}
```

And my logs:

```
sendDeviceInfo getServicesMapInfoById map  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  {"isRoot": true, "visible": true}
4|wscontro | [2017-05-30 12:36:03.010] - debug: /opt/wscontroller/wscontroller-service/scripts/gps GpsController 58a8c61b-f11d-4874-91df-3a5205e4145f sendDeviceInfo sendData.map 1 "{\"isRoot\": true, \"visible\": true}"
```

Why is this happening?

--- solution

```
if(mapData!=undefined){
    var map = mapData.map;
    var aux = map.split('\\').join('');
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(aux);
    sendData.map = jsonObject;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace them like this

```
yourJsonString = yourJsonString.split('\\').join('');
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(yourJsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's nothing to worry about. That "\"s don't actually exist in the string.

When you use JSON.stringify in node.js, the result always has "\"s to escape special characters, and double quotes are special characters. That character is the unix escape character. That's why it appears kind of everywhere.

Comment: The problem is that I send this via post to a endpoint and there this "\" appears...

Comment: If you send that via a POST request and you see those "\"s, it means that the server thinks that it received a string. You have to put a header in the post request as "Content-Type" : "application/json". Then the server will think that it's actually a JSON object and not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code to remove the escape sequence

```
mapData = mapData.replace(/\\"/g, '"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Json string is using "-marks.
Since Json is a string itself, we need a solution to tell the compiler which "-marks are marking the string, and which "-marks are part of the string itself.

To do this it's very common among languages to use the -character, and by typing for instance \", you're 'escaping' the "-mark.

Imagine a string like this: He said to me: "Hi there". Now if we want to make this into a string we could try "He said to me: "Hi there".", though the compiler will see 2 strings and a lost period, because it does not distinguish between the start and end of the string, and the "-marks that are part of the content itself.

When you `console.log()` an actual string, it will not show the "-marks that show the start and end of the string, because it is not necessary. Because of that, there is no need to escape the "-marks in the string itself.

Whatever the `createLog()` function does, it apparently needs to note the string down as it being an actual string, and therefor it needs to escape the "-marks with a '\' sign.