# Split object in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, split

Yesterday i solve my problem spliting my string with "\" but today i have the same problem but with a object...

```
2|wscontro | [2017-05-31 15:57:23.145] - debug: /opt/wscontroller/wscontroller-api/routes/ubus UbusController 63320169-611e-43f5-880e-9b1a13152cfd getDeviceServicesById signature {"config":"wireless","section":"radio0","values":"{\"disabled\":0}"}
2|wscontro | [2017-05-31 15:57:23.145] - debug: /opt/wscontroller/wscontroller-api/routes/ubus UbusController 63320169-611e-43f5-880e-9b1a13152cfd getDeviceServicesById signature "object"
```

I need to have only signature =>
 {"config":"wireless","section":"radio0","values":{"disabled":0"}}

Can anyone help me? I try to convert to String this object and split doing

```
var aux = signature.split('\\').join('');
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(aux);
```

But i get the same result {"config":"wireless","section":"radio0","values":"{\"disabled\":0"}}

My last post: [Split string by "\" Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44261155/split-string-by-node-js/44261293#44261293)

anyone can help?

Comment: {"config":"wireless","section":"radio0","values":"{\"disabled\":0"} is not a correct json

Comment: My bad, my obejct is {"config":"wireless","section":"radio0","values":"{\"disabled\":0}"}

Comment: Catia: your final comment, on an answer, is that your real problem is that your variable seems to be [Object Object]. Can you put that comment in this question, and explain how you're getting the json string into the `signature` variable.

Answer (score 0):

is this you wanted?

```js
var str =' {"config":"wireless","section":"radio0","values":"{\"disabled\":0"}';

console.log(str.replace(/\\/g,''));
```

Comment: this will produce {"config":"wireless","section":"radio0","values":"{"disabled":0"} what is not correct json. You are missing } at the end before last "

Comment: The point is signature is a object.. I tried to do var str = signature.toString().replace(/\\/g,''); and when i console.log i have "\"[object Object]\""

Answer (score 0):

Your object should be like you said in your last comment {"config":"wireless","section":"radio0","values":"{\"disable‌​d\":0}"} then:

```
var jsonstring = "{"config":"wireless","section":"radio0","values":"{\"disable‌​d\":0}"}";
var escapedJsonstring = jsonstring.split('\\').join('');
var json = JSON.parse(escapedJsonstring);
json.parsedValues = JSON.parse(json.values);
console.log(json);
```

Finally you have parsed object in json variable. The main idea is that the values attribute has also string value and not object value. So you need to parse it again as JSON. Result of this parsing is stored in json.parsedValues, but you can rewrite the values string with object using this: json.values = JSON.parse(json.values);